# Firefox and HTML5 audio element don't play well together?

Tags: firefox, html5-audio

On Firefox, A blank space appears above embedded HTML5 audio element's chrome. This appears whenever media starts playing. I tried to figure out where this comes from but couldn't. Is this something that's inherent to Firefox handling html5 audio?

For example I clicked on the example (at the bottom of the post) on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/ , and it looks like below image. (On Firefox).

However, this doesn't happen on Google Chrome and Safari.

[image: HTML5 Audio element with empty region above the control chrome]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with Firefox's implementation of the HTML5 `audio` element. You can work around it with a little extra markup and css.

CSS:

```
<style>
    .wrapper {
        height: 30px;
        position: relative;
    }

    audio {
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <audio src="your/path/file.mp3" controls></audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, It kind of helps, but does not fundamentally solve the problem. The loading animation still appears while audio is still loading up (you know that animated gif). Also, since that loading animation region appears with black background-color, I had to add overflow:hidden to make this sort of work, but then again, this looks like a hack because the progress pointer (the bubble that indicates current min:secs) gets cut off. Anyway, I guess there is no way around this. Is this bug documented anywhere?

Comment: There seems to be several bugs regarding this problem - [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=620317) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=619421)